# LSTM used for regression

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

**Problem**: I have **S** sequences of **T** timesteps each and each timestep contains **F** features so collectively, a dataset of
(S x T x F) and each s in S is described by 2 values (**Target_1** and **Target_2**)

**Goal**: Model/Train an architecture using LSTMs in order to learn/achieve a function approximator model M and given a sequence **s**, to predict **Target_1** and **Target_2** ?

Something like this:

**M**(**s**) ~ (**Target_1**, **Target_2**)

I'm really struggling to find a way, below is a Keras implementation of an example that probably does not work. I made 2 models one for the first Target value and 1 for the second.

```
model1 = Sequential()
model1.add(Masking(mask_value=-10.0))
model1.add(LSTM(1, input_shape=(batch, timesteps, features), return_sequences = True))  
model1.add(Flatten())
model1.add(Dense(hidden_units, activation = "relu"))
model1.add(Dense(1, activation = "linear"))
model1.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.0001))
model1.fit(x_train, y_train[:,0], validation_data=(x_test, y_test[:,0]), epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch, shuffle=False)

model2 = Sequential()
model2.add(Masking(mask_value=-10.0))
model2.add(LSTM(1, input_shape=(batch, timesteps, features), return_sequences=True))
model2.add(Flatten())
model2.add(Dense(hidden_units, activation = "relu"))
model2.add(Dense(1, activation = "linear"))
model2.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.0001))
model2.fit(x_train, y_train[:,1], validation_data=(x_test, y_test[:,1]), epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch, shuffle=False)
```

I want to make somehow good use of LSTMs time relevant memory in order to achieve good regression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can start off with a simple (naive) approach by using two output layers:

```
import tensorflow as tf

timesteps, features = 20, 5
inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input((timesteps, features))
x = tf.keras.layers.Masking(mask_value=-10.0)(inputs)
x = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32, return_sequences=False)(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation = "relu")(x)
output1 = Dense(1, activation = "linear", name='output1')(x)
output2 = Dense(1, activation = "linear", name='output2')(x)

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, [output1, output2])
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001))

x_train = tf.random.normal((500, timesteps, features))
y_train = tf.random.normal((500, 2))
model.fit(x_train, [y_train[:,0],y_train[:,1]] , epochs=5, batch_size=32, shuffle=False)
```

Comment: Thanks alot for the quick and complete answer. Do you think that such approach is suited for the given problem? I have a little problem with understanding how training affects lstm while we backpropagate the gradients through a dense layer that outputs 2 target values. Do LSTMs transform feature space into a new space that's capable of learning with backpropagating mse loss ? Also I see that you chose "return_sequences = False" is there any particular reason for this choice?

Comment: I think this model is more than capable of learning how to predict two target values given a sequence. However, you can and should probably add more hidden layers. Also, ask yourself if `target1` and `target2` can influence each other. You can also calculate the partial derivatives of each output with respect to the inputs to see how the individual features for each time step influence the outputs. Generally, there are a lot of things you can experiment with.